Swiper with React and Snowpack: useState Error
I'm encountering an issue with the Swiper library in my React project, where I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState').
Here’s part of the error trace:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at Object.useState (swiper.react.v11.1.14.js:1624:21)
    at swiper.react.v11.1.14.js:7563:57
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:15494:18)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:19248:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:21678:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:27453:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:26584:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:26493:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:26461:7)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.v18.3.1.js:26113:20)

I’m using TypeScript and Snowpack for my setup, and I’ve already tried multiple solutions without success. The error persists even when I create a minimal repository with only the basic dependencies.
Here’s the link to the minimal repo for reference: https://github.com/KyleSaunders01/swiper-bug-test
I’d really appreciate any advice on how to resolve this, especially if you've had experience with Swiper in a Snowpack environment. Thanks!
What I Tried:
I updated Swiper and React to ensure compatibility, externalized react and react-dom in my Snowpack config, and tested a minimal setup with just Swiper and basic slides. I also tried disabling features like Pagination and Navigation, downgrading Swiper, and disabling React Fast Refresh.
What I Expected:
I expected Swiper to render the slides correctly without triggering the useState error, and for the page to load without any runtime errors.
What Actually Happened:
Despite all my attempts, the useState error persists. Even in the minimal setup with only basic dependencies installed, the error still occurs.

Swiper v11.x may not fully support React 18, leading to compatibility issues. Downgrading to Swiper v8 (which is widely compatible with React 18) might solve the issue.

Thx for the quick response. I've tried this but I'm still getting the same error, unfortunately. I will update the repo with this recommendation though :)
